# 500 (Internal Server Error) transform node request to fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, request, fetch

Hi i am using react native and i have a request in node with request js. I dont want to make the request on the server anymore. I want to do it at the frontend. I decided to use fetch.
But when i do the same request on the frontend i get internal server error 500
I only want the cookie which i get from the response.

**This works in node:**

```
var request = require('request');


var dataString2 = 'lmaction=doLogin&username=XXX&password=XXX';

var options2 = {
    url: 'https://onlineservice.klarmobil.de/login',
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
    'Host': 'onlineservice.klarmobil.de',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.klarmobil.de/',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Cookie': '_gali=kundenlogin'
},,
    body: dataString2
};

function callback2(error, response, body) {
    const cookie= response.headers['set-cookie'][0].split(";")[0] 
}

request(options2, callback2);
```

**And this is my code in react native:**

```
fetch('https://onlineservice.klarmobil.de/login', {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    body: 'lmaction=doLogin&username=xxx&password=xxx'
    headers:{
        'Host': 'onlineservice.klarmobil.de',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
        'Referer': 'https://www.klarmobil.de/',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'Cookie': '_gali=kundenlogin'
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error))
  .then((res)=>{
    console.log(res)
    const cookie= response.headers['set-cookie'][0].split(";")[0] 
    console.log(cookie)
  })
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: `i get internal server error 500` - check the server logs for the reason for the error

Comment: the server for the request is not from me. Did you get internal server error 500 with node?

Comment: did I? no, but I didn't run your code - by the way, I don't think you can set cookie header (or referer) in fetch (it may be different in react native though) - is there any way you can see exactly what the request is sending - some sort of debugging you can do

Comment: the service i call with this request is not from me. With node it works. I only get error 500 with fetch and react native

Comment: obviously the request has something missing, but unless you can debug exactly what request headers and body look like that's going to be hard

Comment: What is the difference between request and fetch? I thought it is the same request. One is with node and the other with fetch and react native. Maybe i can use request js and not fetch in react native?

Answer (score 1):

If I execute this with Chromes native `fetch`, it does not include the `Cookie` header (as Jaromanda X guessed).

Furthermore, it seems you cannot override the `Referer` (and likely some other protected headers), for me it is being sent with the current site ("https://stackoverflow.com/"). This seems to be the cause of the problem, if I send anything but the "klarmobil" Referer the 500 error occurs:

```
curl -i "https://onlineservice.klarmobil.de/login" -H "Origin: https://stackoverflow.com" -H "Accept-Encoding: r" -H "Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Referer: https://www.klarmobil.de/" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "DNT: 1" --data "lmaction=doLogin^&username=xxx^&password=xxx"
-> 200

curl -i "https://onlineservice.klarmobil.de/login" -H "Origin: https://stackoverflow.com" -H "Accept-Encoding: r" -H "Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Referer: https://stackoverflow.com/" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "DNT: 1" --data "lmaction=doLogin^&username=xxx^&password=xxx"
-> 500
```

Also, I don't think it's ethical nor a good idea to programmatically login on a foreign site "forging" requests and extracting cookies like that. As they don't offer an API for this, this is likely not intended. They may also change their login system at any time and your program breaks.

Comment: i dont want to make bad things with this. I just want to get my consumed data volume from mobile provider. Do you know how can i solve this? Should I route the request to a server which makes the request or can i use request.js in react native? Has an app in react native the same behaviour like google chrome? Chrome does it not allow to set some header options because of security reasons, but in react native, too?

Comment: `Should I route the request to a server which makes the request` - yes

Comment: Yes, this might not fully apply to react-native fetch. I wanted to share my findings regardless, as it shows a reproduceable situation for the 500 and the parameter to fix it. You would need to debug the actual request sent off by your app and check what headers it includes.

Comment: Proxying your request through a server seems like a good idea anyways.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your programmatic issue: You can easily see your consumed data by visiting http://datapass.de via your mobile network in Telekom provided networks like klarmobil.